# iPod classic is not detected in iTunes or my computer

Tags: windows-7, ipod

I think my iPod may have had the settings changed from Windows to Mac. Now my iPod is not detected by iTunes or my computer. How can I restore the factory settings on my iPod without using iTunes or my computer?

Answer (score 0):

Using an apple wall charger only, leave it plugged in charging overnight. When an iPod is completely dead it can't be reset until it has at least 20% charge.

Comment: its fully charged it needs restoring t0 factory settings not resetting

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling iTunes? This helps a lot sometimes.

Also, have you tried the five steps to solve iPod Issues?

The five steps are:

1. Reset
2. Retry
3. Restart
4. Reinstall
5. Restore

Here’s a link for [how to do this on the iPod Classic](http://web.archive.org/web/20140304085927/http://www.apple.com/support/ipod/five_rs/classic/#).

You should solve it on the first steps.

Comment: ive tried every step on the apple support but nothing has worked. im positive its because the ipod is set to use with a mac, which i dont have. all the troubleshoot options tell me to restore factory settings using itunes or my computer but i cannot access either with the ipod

Comment: @Dale Your computer can't see the ipod at all??? not even to store data?

Comment: no not even to store data

Comment: is your cable ok?